# How to get text from webelement

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

There is some textbox and text inside, this text is not visible on html source of the page but is visible on UI.
Here is this text box:

```
>  <textarea id="emails-list" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-
> required" as-email-list=";" ng-class="{'has-error':
> model.hasError(kpiForm,  'emailsList')}"
> ng-model="model.formData.recipients" required="" rows="10" cols="30"
> name="emailsList"></textarea>
```

It's ng-model, should I use protractor for this purpose? any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried? You don't have to use `protractor` just because it's an `ng-model`

Comment: I didn't have deal with such elements till now so I a bit confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of `protractor`, find the element [by model](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model) and get [the value of the `value` attribute](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#the-result-of-gettext-from-an-input-element-is-always-empty):

```
element(by.model('model.formData.recipients')).getAttribute('value');
```

or, [by id](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.id):

```
element(by.id('emails-list')).getAttribute('value');
```

In case of `java` selenium bindings, *find the element by id*:

```
driver.findElement(By.id('emails-list')).getAttribute('value');
```